saddle discomfort
I have experienced discomfort in the saddle for years.  I think that ever since I migrated to clipless pedals, I noticed it more.  For about the first 15 minutes, I feel like my sit bones are bruising, and then after that, I feel 'okay' in the saddle.  For the first 15 minutes, I shuffle and get out of the saddle to release some discomfort.  After that, my body tolerates it.
I came across:
Why do I do the "saddle shuffle" when riding?
I tend to shuffle in the saddle.
I was fitted when I was out on a bike tour and my observation has been that for the first week or 2 after adjusting my bike, the shuffle was eliminated.  Perhaps part of it was forcing myself to not shuffle in the saddle and the other part was that when I was out on tour, I was putting out substantially less power than when I ride at home for the simple reason that I was covering more distance out on tour.
At the time of fitting, I was on a trainer riding at a slightly harder effort than my touring effort, probably similar to my effort at home, but for less time and on level ground the entire time.  But, at least for me, I feel that I tend to sit in different positions depending on the inclination of the bike.  For instance, if I am climbing, I tend to sit toward the nose of the saddle, flat, in the middle, and down hill, toward the back of completely off the back as if in a mountain biking position.
That said, I feel like making a concerted effort to spin rather than grind as well as not move in the saddle (including getting out of the saddle) results in less saddle discomfort.
I also measured my sit bones at home after watching Specialized's video.  I didn't have much luck with cardboard, but instead felt for the bony protrusions and then got a ruler between the 2 points and measured.  I think I am roughly 115 mm and my saddle is a new Specialized (something) 143 mm.
I also swapped out my stem for a 10mm shorter one as during the fit, my bike fitter suggested I try a 10mm shorter stem along with dropping the stem 10mm (removing a spacer).  The parts weren't available at the time of my fitting.
I tried 1 ride with the new stem and feel I am in a better position.
My questions then are:

the saddle discomfort I am describing is not normal.
What should I feel in the saddle?  I am guessing it should feel fairly neutral or at least not painful.  Should I feel the rotation of my hips on the saddle?  The saddle itself should not move or follow my pedals strokes, instead it should be relatively unmoving (my old saddle followed my pedals strokes).

EDIT:
I saw a chiropractor and explained my discomfort and am thinking that perhaps my issue is that my hips or something else is out of alignment.  Not only are my sit bones uncomfortable, but also, both my left and right feet are uncomfortable right around the ball of the foot.  Previously, my right foot was always uncomfortable on the outside of the foot and I know that my right foot was not flat, but instead outside of the foot down and inside up.  Now, I think I'm doing the opposite.  I also notice this discomfort when walking.
EDIT:
I tried an Ergon SMC saddle and the discomfort is still there albeit a little muted.  My sit bones feel 'bruised', but according to:
https://road.cc/content/feature/how-spot-ischial-bursitis-and-stop-it-ruining-your-ride-277533
I don't believe my sit bones are 'bruised' by that definition because I don't feel a lump in that area, the bone just hurts if I press firmly against it.
Probably, the best thing to do is take time off riding and then have a reset to ensure I'm sitting properly in the saddle in the first place to ensure the pain doesn't return.
EDIT:
I finally decided to try altering the bike setup from where it was when I was fitted.  I merely angled the nose of the saddle down 1 notch and feel that is better even with the stiffer saddle I was fitted on.  The side effect of that is increased pressure on the hands and arms.
EDIT:
I measured my sit bone width at my local bike shop instead of at home and got roughly the same thing 110 mm.
EDIT:
My left knee is about 1-in forward of my right knee which again points to my hips being out of alignment and why I seem to be unable to get comfortable in the saddle.  According to this, it points to being tight and stretching is in order:
https://www.roadbikerider.com/bicycling-options-different-leg-lengths/
The saddle doesn't feel uncomfortable, but I don't feel stable in the saddle.  I don't feel the saddle is directly to blame, but most likely the lack of flexibility.  I will see about stretching, massage, and chiropractic care to see if that helps.

There are people who will never be comfortable on a conventional bike. If you happen to be one of them, think out of the box. For me that happened to be recumbent bikes.

First a disclaimer: I'm not a professional bike fitter, and more information should probably be needed for an more accurate answer. The chamois plays a big role for example, but it's not mentioned in the question. The seatpost also plays a big role, as a compliant one will lower the shocks to the sitbones (but from what is described, that aspect seems secondary). But I can answer the written questions, that do not require advanced bike fitting knowledge.
The saddle discomfort you describe is not normal. If you don't cycle regularly, it's normal to feel a bit of pain in the beginning, but if your saddle is well positioned (height, angle, fore/aft), well sized and your chamois/padding is suited for your use, you shouldn't feel pain like you describe. On my side, I do experience some light saddle pain after 4-5 hours of gravel for what it's worth, but I feel it more the next day if I sit on a bike without wearing a chamois.
A bit of hip movement on the saddle is normal: given the dynamics of pedaling it would be impossible to not move the hips a bit when pedaling, but too much movement can be the sign of a compensation of an unfit saddle. For example, hip movement is often mentioned in bike fitting material as a compensation for a too high saddle. For what it's worth, I'm using a SQLab 611 Ergowave Active on my "flat bar gravel", this saddle has an elastomer to damp lateral rotational movements - but to nuance, it's a very flat saddle (laterally), so it needs to rely on that kind of "mechanism" to compensate hip movements — with a regular saddle, you can have a bit of rotation. According to SQLab's marketing material, humans are not designed to sit on "branches", but on flatter surfaces, so they design rather flat saddles that can rotate laterally, their design works well to my experience, but I'm also satisfied with the Specialized Power saddle, that is probably the most opposite design you can have.
If you have a compliant seatpost (carbon/steel/titanium), it's also normal that the saddle moves up and down when you pedal. The harder you push, the lower the weight on the saddle, which would translate into a slight raise of the saddle — if I remember correctly, Canyon for example recommends to a 1cm increase of the saddle position for their VCLS 2.0 seat post compared to a rigid post — the most compliant seat post on the market, so of course when you pedal, it can move up to 1cm.
For what you describe about changing the position on the saddle when climbing/descending, I had that with the stock saddle of my bike, that was very flat at the rear — longitudinally (it's common for off-road saddles to have a small "step"), but I think it's one of the instances where the saddle design was inadequate: when going uphill (over 10%), I was sliding back to the rear, and this was exacerbated by the fact that I didn't know that it's recommended to not wear underwear over a chamois, as the underwear/chamois interface was "sliding", so even if the bib short stayed on the saddle, I was moving back when pedalling uphill, so I was also constantly "shuffling", and trying to stay more one the nose of the saddle. This was solved by a saddle that had a less flat design - longitudinally (the SQLab I mentioned above, but many off-road saddles have a "step" or an "angle" to limit rear movement when pedaling uphill), that prevented the sliding movement.

Note that I bought the SQLab initially for back pain issues (this saddle scores very well on reviews for that), it helped but the most important component for that was the seat post, the bike had an aluminium frame and seat post. I usually don't like to endorse products, but given it has a very distinctive shape from most saddles, it may be worth considering. Taking the "Active" version is worth the expense, IMHO.

Personally, I use a Selle SMP saddle.
I agree with all the points you have made in question 1 and 2.
You've done the right thing measuring your seat bone.
I recommend you listen to Neil Stanbury who starts at 1 minute and 40 seconds into the second video link bellow, and also recommend the first link.
Hopefully it will give you more insight and information to know what is your next step to resolve your issue.
[Best saddle][1]:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngQHwX4hHrc
[Sore saddle][2]:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJ4-Cx5s1kE
